# Best way of creating an array from vectors

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

x,y,z are three vectors.

If I run three for loops in matlab and stock at each iteration `A(i,j,k) = [x(i) y(j) z(k)]`, then I will get an array.

What is the most efficient way of creating this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation you used in the question (`A(i,j,k) = [x(i) y(j) z(k)]`) has a bug. It creates a 3D matrix A and tried to assign a value to it's (i,j,k) element, only you assign 3 values (x(i),y(j),z(k)).

So if I understand you correctly, what you meant is:

```
A = [x(:) , y(:),  z(:)] ;
```

this will give and array of size 3xn. Unless you actually meant to have a 3d matrix, then look into `ndgrid` \ `meshgrid` options.

Comment: this is actually what I meant (ndgrid)